# Unrecognized selector set to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to use the `makeObjectsPerformSelector` method.

This is my code.
I don't understand why when I call `makeObjectsPerformSelector` with the selector `uppercase:` it doesn't find it...

```
#import "testAppViewController.h"

@interface testAppViewController ()
- (void)uppercase;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *arrayTest;

@end

@implementation testAppViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self start];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)uppercase
{
    NSLog(@"---");
}

- (void) start
{
    self.arrayTest = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [self.arrayTest addObject:@"toto"];
    [self.arrayTest addObject:@"tata"];
    [self.arrayTest addObject:@"titi"];
    [self.arrayTest addObject:@"tutu"];


    for (NSString *s in self.arrayTest)
        NSLog(@"1 - %@", s);

    [self.arrayTest makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(uppercase)];

    for (NSString *s in self.arrayTest)
        NSLog(@"2 - %@", s);
}
```

Comment: Could it be because there's no such method on `NSString`?

Comment: @JoshCaswell I tryed both it doesn't change.

Comment: @JoshCaswell with a param an with no param. I'm new in Objective-C dev. You don't have to be rude ...

Comment: @middaparka I tryed it doesn't work, I've edited my code

Comment: I've made a mistake when I edited the code on stack. But it was ok in my code. But I still have the error.

Comment: @middaparka doesn't change.

Comment: You don't have to be defensive. Explain what you're trying to do and what you expected to happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`makeObjectsPerformSelector` calls the method on the objects in the array, not on a method in your class (which is effectively completely unrelated to the array contents). So, the error is because `NSString` doesn't have an `uppercase` method (with or without a parameter).

`NSString` does have an `uppercaseString` method, but that won't help you either because it returns a value and that would be lost when using `makeObjectsPerformSelector`.

You probably want to iterate the array contents using some other method to process the strings.

Comment: Oh ok, I completely misunderstand the makeObjectsPerformSelector utility. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

`makeObjectsPerformSelector:` will send the specified selector to each object in your array.

So you are sending `uppercase:` to each NSString in your array. But NSString does not have a method called `uppercase:`. You implemented the method in *your own* class.

But even if you would call uppercaseString (which NSString implements) that won't work because an object can't replace itself.

One way to make this work is a category on `NSMutableString`.

```
@interface NSMutableString (MBUpperCase)
- (void)makeUpperCase;
@end

@implementation NSMutableString (MBUpperCase)
- (void)makeUpperCase {
    [self setString:[self uppercaseString]];
}
@end



    NSMutableArray *arrayTest = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [arrayTest addObject:[@"toto" mutableCopy]];
    [arrayTest addObject:[@"tata" mutableCopy]];
    [arrayTest addObject:[@"titi" mutableCopy]];
    [arrayTest addObject:[@"tutu" mutableCopy]];


    NSLog(@"%@", arrayTest);

    [arrayTest makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(makeUpperCase)];

    NSLog(@"%@", arrayTest);
```

**But you should probably not do this at all. This smells very very bad.**

This is much better:

```
NSMutableArray *upperCaseArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[arrayTest count]];
for (NSString *string in arrayTest) {
    [upperCaseArray addObject:[string uppercaseString]];
}
```